# Ajax asynchronous callback beforesend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am doing the following ajax call:

```
def myfunction(var1, var2){
b1. $.ajax({
        url: 'some_url2',
        type: "POST",
        data: {'mydata': var1, 'mydata2': var2},
        success: function (data) {
b2.        document.getElementById("successMessageAlert").style.display = "none";
        },
        error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
            alert('error1 occurred');
b3.  }
}

def function1() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'some_url',
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            var aData = JSON.parse(data);
b4.         myfunction(getCookie('selected_Id'), aData);
b5.         document.getElementById("successMessageAlert").style.display = "block";
b6.         document.getElementById("successMessageText").innerHTML = "<strong>Success!</strong> The encoding record was saved successfully.";
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
            alert('error occurred')
        }
    });
}
```

I am also using the following piece of code for csrf:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that statements after the `myfunction` are getting executed before `myfunction`. So, "successMessageAlert" shows up briefly before getting hidden again.

I used some breakpoints (b1-b6). Following is their execution order:

1. b4
2. b1
3. b3
4. b5
5. b6
6. b2
7. b3

Based on reading several related SO posts, I know that this issue has to do something with asynchronous nature of ajax calls, the `beforesend` function and callbacks but I am not able to put 2 and 2 together. Please help.

PS: I need to change the title of the post. But I am not able to describe this issue succinctly.

Comment: 1. What does `beforeSend` have to do with `myfunction`? 2. What statements after `myfunction` are being executed before it?

Comment: Both the statements after `myfunction` gets executed even before a call is made to `myfunction`. I think it has something to do with `beforesend` because I tried the debugger and it seems to be taking me through the `csrfSafeMethod` before calling `myfunction`

Comment: I can assure you with 100% cetainity that the successMessageXXX lines are not executed before `myfunction`. Use a debugger to see what really happens and is confusing you (set a breakpoint on each of these lines)

Comment: Sure @Amit give me a few minutes.. I will traceout the exact path.. I hope that will be helpful

Comment: okk.. I am able to trace.. let me edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually , the execution flow is absolutely correct. I  don't consider it as anything to do with `beforeSend` Now you need to understand the nature of the JavaScript ajax call. Ajax Call are `asynchronous` in nature.

`asynchronous` means whenever a ajax call get executed then JavaScript doesn't wait for call to get completed and moves to next line of code.

For example In your case

After `b1` code moved to `b3` --> Because JavaScript doesn't wait for call to get complete

Now Question is when will `b2` get executed.

It depends on the network traffic, as soon as the ajax call is complete the `b2` code will executed.

How to handles these case :

There are two ways

a) I will not suggest this i.e use `async:false` as a parameter in ajax call. When this parameter given in ajax call , It tell JavaScript to wait for

`b2` and not to proceed to `b3`.

Why I don't suggest this

The call is synchronous i.e in case your request take 3 second to complete, then your site will unresponsive for 3 second.

b) Second approach use callback :

This one is bit complicated but is the best approach.

Firstly you need to identify the code which depend on the ajax call completion , you can place all that code inside a function and get it executed once the ajax call completes

Below is the example :

```
    def myfunction(var1, var2 , callback){
     $.ajax({
            url: 'some_url2',
            type: "POST",
            data: {'mydata': var1, 'mydata2': var2},
            success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("successMessageAlert").style.display = "none";
            callback(); //execute the passed function now
            },
            error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
                alert('error1 occurred');
      }
    }  





      def function1() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'some_url',
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                var aData = JSON.parse(data);
                     myfunction(getCookie('selected_Id'), aData ,function(){

                          //Code will get executed after ajax call completes

                         document.getElementById("successMessageAlert").style.display = "block";
                         document.getElementById("successMessageText").innerHTML = "<strong>Success!</strong> The encoding record was saved successfully.";          
                     });
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
                alert('error occurred')
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: aahaa.. this was the response I was looking for Sanjeev. I knew I had to use callback and it was happening because of the asynchronous nature, but I wasn't able to put it all together. But then Prashant's answer, made me understand the flow and you have not only explained it in a better way but have also given a solution that works without using the depreciated `async=false` call.  Thank you so much Sanjeev.

Comment: Well i truly appreciate this as a good knowledge for me-@Sanjeev

Answer (score 1):

try using `async:false` in you `myfunction` ajax call like this

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'some_url2',
            type: "POST",
            async:false,
            data: {'mydata': var1, 'mydata2': var2},
            success: function (data) {
           document.getElementById("successMessageAlert").style.display = "none";
            },
            error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
                alert('error1 occurred');
      }
```

Please mark an answer if it helps

Comment: aah.. I think I understand.. so, `myfunction` is getting called in order, but because it is an asynchronous call, the statements following the function starts getting executed. But isn't making ajax calls asynchronous frowned upon ?

Comment: yes it will never make an async call but yeah if you want your statements to be executed as your requirement this is a way i thought....

Comment: Thanks @prashant. Can you suggest a better solution such that I don't do async=false and still am able to hide/show the element in order ??

Comment: @TheWanderer I dont think so dude..... because if your myfunction does ajax call you have to go with async:false or else your next statements will be executed untill the call is done.... i hope it helps you

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you for your quick thinking. I have accepted the answer and upvoted it as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86581/discussion-between-prashant-patil-and-the-wanderer).

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, ajax calls return a [**jqXHR**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object for asynchronous processing. Among other capabilities, it has a `.done` function that attaches a callback to receive the ajax result once the request is done. It's very useful to return and use this object as it opens the door for various kinds of continued processing.

*As noted in other answers, it's not a great idea to force ajax calls to behave synchronously as that will block all other processing and can result in very poor UX.*

You should use that in your code to only manipulate the UI once that happens:

```
function myfunction(var1, var2){
  // I guess the "successMessageAlert" should be here, no?
  document.getElementById("successMessageAlert").style.display = "none";
  return $.ajax({
        url: 'some_url2',
        type: "POST",
        data: {'mydata': var1, 'mydata2': var2},
/*       success: function (data) {
           document.getElementById("successMessageAlert").style.display = "none";
        },*/ // <- Bring this back if that's really what you wanted...
        error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
            alert('error1 occurred');
  }
}

function function1() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'some_url',
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
          var aData = JSON.parse(data);
          myfunction(getCookie('selected_Id'), aData).done(function () {
            document.getElementById("successMessageAlert").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("successMessageText").innerHTML = "<strong>Success!</strong> The encoding record was saved successfully.";
          });
        },
        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
            alert('error occurred')
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It seems `.done` capability was specifically designed to do such changes. How would you contrast `.done` with `callback` ? It is just a different way of performing the callback without modifying the `myfunction` parameters ?

Comment: `.done` is just one of a set of functionality features in the jqxHR object. It's desgined to allow asynchronous processing including chaining of async operations, where as a callback is a single entry point. The modification of the `myfunction` parameters is not the important point here (returning a value is also "modifying" the function behavior)